# Приложение в Android Studio по вставке пропущенного слова

Tags: java, android

Имеется много текста со звездочками (пропущены слова). Подскажите, как написать приложение, в котором выводился этот текст, а вместо звёздочек - поле для ввода.
Вручную создавать такое Activity не подойдёт, текста очень много. Нужно частично показывать его на экране, создавая вместо звёздочек поля для ввода, и после ввода переходить к следующему тексту, сохраняя результат.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, создайте элемент EditText и кнопки для навигации по вашим звездочкам. При переходе к очередным звездочкам показывайте в соответствующем элементе часть текста, в которой содержатся эти звездочки (например, N символов до и N символов после звездочек).

Либо поделите текст на массив строк, где в качестве разделителя будут служить звездочки. Далее программно добавляйте PlainText с текстом элемента массива и после него поле для ввода. И так для всего массива.

Comment: Сделал с массивом строк, добавляя PlainText и после поле для ввода. Но теперь текст вылезает за пределы экрана. Пробовал с разными Layout.